# Sharing User Data Between Android Apps in Java: How to Display Username from One App to Another

Tags: java, android

I'm working on two Android applications, and I want to display the username from the first app in the second app if the user is logged in. If the user isn't logged in, I'd like to display a message prompting them to log in to the first app.  Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this in Android using Java? Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

First i tried with share preference but i just found out that i can't use that for sharing data for one app to another so how i can?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I added an answer to your question below. If this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be to create a backend service where the user can log in entering their credentials. There are [articles](https://harshitabambure.medium.com/login-api-with-retrofit-and-mvvm-with-auto-login-in-android-kotlin-bb6907092e0c) available that provide an example on how to use the [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to do so, however you would also need to create some sort of backend service. For testing purposes, you could set up a [local demo server using NodeJS](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/create-nodejs-web-server).

There used to be the option to set a [sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) flag in the manifest.xml files for both apps. As a result, the apps with the same user ID could access each other's private file directory. This is deprecated though with API29.

However, to address your original question, two apps can communicate in Android using [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent). So one approach would be to add an `<intent-filter>` to the LoginMaster app. The LoginClient app then calls that intent, the LoginMaster app is openend, and returns whether the user is logged in.

The code below is just there to provide you with a general direction, so you will have to adjust it according to your needs. Please be aware that this does not protect the sent username. So don't use this method to pass sensitive data.

**1.)** Add a new Activity to the manifest.xml of your LoginMaster app. This app will have no visible layout (Theme.NoDisplay), its only purpose is to return whether a user is logged in. We attach a custom intent by which other apps can start this Activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginProvider"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="your.app.loginmaster/customintent" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**2.)** Implement the LoginProvider Activity class. This class handles the incoming request from the LoginClient app and then sends a response intent.

```
public class LoginProvider extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent requestIntent = getIntent();
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra("userName ");    
        Intent mResultIntent = new Intent("your.name.loginmaster.RESULT_ACTION");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, mResultIntent);  //default is cancelled

        // Perform your logic to check whether the given user is logged in here in the LoginMaster app
        UserLoginService loginService = new UserLoginService(getApplicationContext);
        if(loginService.isUserLoggedIn(userName)) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mResultIntent);
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

**3.)** Now call the newly created Activity from your ClientLogin app. The code for that is placed into a variable of type `ActivityResultLauncher`. Just declare it at the top of your Activity class as a global variable:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> isLoggedInActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result == null || result.getData() == null) return;
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is not logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

**4.)** Finally, to trigger the login check, start the activity using the following code:

```
Intent mRequestFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        mRequestFileIntent.setType("your.app.loginmaster/customintent");
mRequestFileIntent.putExtra("userName", "myFunnyUsername123");
statsTransferActivityResult.launch(mRequestFileIntent);
```

You now should have a Toast printing out whether the user is logged in or not.